# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType' (settings.py)

Tags: python, django

settings.py

```
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT=bool(int(os.environ.get('SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT')))
```

I retrieve the following error:

```
line 57, in <module>
    SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT=bool(int(os.environ.get('SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT')))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

please solve this

Comment: Your `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` is not set in your `os.environ`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` is not set in your `os.environ`. If that is the case, then the `os.environ.get('SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT')` will return `None`, and the `int(…)` function can thus not convert a `None` object to an `int`.

What you can do is specify a default in case the setting is missing, for example:

```
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT=bool(int(os.environ.get('SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT', 0)))
```

But likely something is wrong with your environment variables: no `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` environment variable is set. You will need to specify these *before* running the `manage.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

Non-Type just means that there isn't any value in the variable. Try fixing that first.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

**Set default value for get() func:**

```
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT=bool(int(os.environ.get('SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT', 0)))
```